# Pandas - Convert strings in a list to integers using a dictionary and sum values

Tags: pandas

I have a df with lists as cell values:

```
    team_id             results
        262     [v, v, e, v, e] 
        263     [e, v, v, d, e]
```

And I have a dictionary:

```
convert_dict = {'v':3, 'e':1, 'd':0}
```

---

Now I would like to convert every string value inside the list to its correspondent dict value, add all values and end up with:

```
    team_id     results
        262          11 
        263          10
```

---

For the conversion, I have tried:

```
df['results'] = df['results'].map(lambda x: convert_dict[x])
```

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.assign(result = lambda x: x['result'].apply(lambda values: sum(convert_dict.get(v, np.nan) for v in values)))

# Or if you don't like .assign()

df['result'] = df['result'].apply(lambda values: sum(convert_dict.get(v, np.nan) for v in values))
```